# remove breaks from php url string?

Tags: php, string, variables, replace

I for the life of me can't figure this out...

I've got a form, it ends up passing some fields as a query string.

```
$f = $_GET['full'];
$t = $_GET['title'];

$illegal = array("&#039;", "#039;");
$f = str_replace($illegal, "", $f);
$t = str_replace($illegal, "", $t);
```

For some weird reason, apostrophes where messing up what I need, so I removed them as they were turning up (' for the first occurance and #039; afterwards).

Now $t outputs a useable string. $f however can contain breaks. And they end up in the string as

```
<br+%2F>
```

I've tried

```
$f = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "", $f);
```

and

```
$breaks = array("<br+%2F>", "/\r?\n/", "<br />");
$f = str_replace($breaks, "%20", $f);
```

but when i output it in a url I STILL get

```
http://www.domain.com?t=good%20string&f=bad<br+%2F>string
```

The  is causing a 404 page not found error. :(

**EDIT**

```
$f = html_entity_decode($_GET['full']);
$t = html_entity_decode($_GET['title']);

$illegal = array("&#039;", "#039;");
$f = str_replace($illegal, "", $f);
$t = str_replace($illegal, "", $t);

$f = htmlspecialchars($f);

$breaks = array("<br+%2F>%0D%0A<br+%2F>%0D%0A", "<br+%2F>%0D%0A");
$f = str_replace($breaks, "%20", $f);

if (---private-stuff---) {
header( 'Location: /?title=' . $t . '&full=' . $f . '&fifth=fith%20percent');
}
```

The last $f STILL contains

```
<br+%2F>%0D%0A<br+%2F>%0D%0A
```

in the url. Shouldn't ONE of those functions stripped it out?!?

Comment: A 404 means the URL address is invalid. Meaning you should try `http://www.domain.com/index.php?...`

Comment: I understand what a 404 is - but http://www.domain.com?t=good%20string&f=bad<br+%2F>string is giving a 404. If i cut out the <br+%2F>, it works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [html entities decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
$string = html_entity_decode("&#039;");
echo $string ; // '
```

so in your case that will be

```
$f = html_entity_decode($_GET['full']);
$t = html_entity_decode($_GET['title']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting a 404, it may be that you have a .htaccess rule (ModRewrite) that is trying to route you to some other page (that does not exist).  Sounds like you may have two separate issues...

To get your actual text back out of the query string, Ibu is correct...use html_entity_decode()

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I submit the form, it works just fine, I get redirected to the right page. If I submit the form but have breaks (hit enter) in the <textarea> I get redirected to the 404. all I have to do is cut out the <br+%2F> and go, and it works.

Comment: if you are getting a 404, that means your server is looking for a page that does not exist.  Since you are not editing the submit path for the form, obviously SOMETHING else is changing where the form submission is being directed.  This is most likely in your .htaccess file in some rule that is not understanding the new URL string.  Either way, the issue is in your server configs rather than the actual form.  The easiest workaround if you can't figure it out is to submit your form as a POST rather than a GET, as this will keep the info out of the URL.  POST is a better practice too.

Comment: Also, you are doing a str_replace on html entities that have already been decoded...so you will not find them in their encoded format.  That is why they are not being stripped.
$f = html_entity_decode($_GET['full']);
$f = str_replace('<br />', ' ', $f);

then re-encode the string before appending to the header(Location:).